# Windows Batch extract variable names and replace values

Tags: sql, string, dynamic, batch-file

So I have a file that looks something like this:

```
DECLARE   
  P_IBSP_YEAR VARCHAR2(32767);  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR VARCHAR2(32767);  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH VARCHAR2(32767);  
  ERROR_LEVEL VARCHAR2(32767);  

BEGIN   
  P_IBSP_YEAR := NULL;  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR := 2013;  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH := January;  
  ERROR_LEVEL := NULL;  

  T2_GDA.GDA.MAIN_RUN_ALL ( P_IBSP_YEAR, P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR, P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH, ERROR_LEVEL );  
  COMMIT;   
END;
```

1- I want to know how many variables there are after BEGIN (in this case there are four of them:P_IBSP_YEAR, P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR, P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH, ERROR_LEVEL)
2- I want to replace the value they have (what appears after the ":= ") with the first 20 characters of the variable name bounded by percentage signs.

Things to keep in mind:

a) I do not know ahead of time how many variables will be in the file (there might be one or more)

Example of output I want:

```
DECLARE   
  P_IBSP_YEAR VARCHAR2(32767);  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR VARCHAR2(32767);  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH VARCHAR2(32767);  
  ERROR_LEVEL VARCHAR2(32767);  

BEGIN   
  P_IBSP_YEAR := %P_IBSP_YEAR%;  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR := %P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR%;  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH := %P_CD_PROCESSING_MONT%;  
  ERROR_LEVEL := %ERROR_LEVEL%;  

  T2_GDA.GDA.MAIN_RUN_ALL ( P_IBSP_YEAR, P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR, P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH, ERROR_LEVEL );  
  COMMIT;   
END;
```

[Notice that the variable P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH  became %P_CD_PROCESSING_MONT% because it was longer than 20 characters]

Here is what I have so far. It works, but it is very static since I need to modify my script every time I use another file. Because I am hard coding the variable names:

```
@echo off  

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('type %sql_file%') do CALL :DOREPLACE "%%f"  

GOTO AFTER_FOR  
:DOREPLACE  

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
SET OUTPUT_1=%*  

set OUTPUT_2=!OUTPUT_1:P_IBSP_YEAR;=%P_IBSP_YEAR%; !  

set OUTPUT_3=!OUTPUT_2:P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR;=%P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR%; !  

set OUTPUT_4=!OUTPUT_3:P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH;=%P_CD_PROCESSING_MONT%; !  

set OUTPUT_5=!OUTPUT_4:ERROR_LEVEL;=%ERROR_LEVEL%; !  

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%g in ('ECHO %OUTPUT_5%') do ECHO %%~g>>%sql_file%.tmp  

EXIT /b  


:AFTER_FOR  

echo The modified temporary sql script now looks like this  
echo.  
type %sql_file%.tmp
```

What I would like to have would look more like this:

I want a variable "n" that is based on the number of variables I have in my original file. This value n is incremented after every command. This way I wouldn't have 1, 2, 3, ... like I do right now. But always 'n'

```
SET OUTPUT_1=%*

set OUTPUT_2=!OUTPUT_1:Full_var1_name;=%FIRST_20_CHARACTERS_OF_VAR1%;!

set OUTPUT_3=!OUTPUT_2:Full_var2_name;=%FIRST_20_CHARACTERS_OF_VAR2%; !

set OUTPUT_4=!OUTPUT_3:Full_var3_name;=%FIRST_20_CHARACTERS_OF_VAR3%; !

set OUTPUT_5=!OUTPUT_4:Full_var4_name;=%FIRST_20_CHARACTERS_OF_VAR4%; !

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%g in ('ECHO %OUTPUT_5%') do ECHO %%~g>>%sql_file%.tmp

EXIT /b
```

Sorry about this long message. And thank you :)

Comment: Are you saying that you want a batch-only solution that can parse any input file with assignment statements each containing unknown identifier?  This seems to be expecting too much from a batch file.  I have done something similar but thru 'sed' and 'antlr'.

Comment: Basically I want to:  :
a) Count the number of variables. Those can be identified by the fact that they end by a space and a colon " :"
b) save those variables using some kind of for loop (n being the number of variables:

for /l %x in (1, 1, %n%)
var%n% = (string before the "space:" )


Using another for loop, replace:

First "n" lines after the word BEGIN

semi-colon and everything that comes before it until the space, with  first twenty characters of var%n% bounded by percentages and finishing with semi colon;

Comment: Therefore transforming this:  

...  
BEGIN  
  P_IBSP_YEAR := NULL;  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR := 2013;  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH := January;  
  ERROR_LEVEL := NULL;  
  
Into this:

  P_IBSP_YEAR := NULL;
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR := 2013;
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH := January;
  ERROR_LEVEL := NULL;

  
Into this:  
...  
BEGIN    
  P_IBSP_YEAR := %P_IBSP_YEAR%;  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR := %P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR%;  
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH := %P_CD_PROCESSING_MONT%;  
  ERROR_LEVEL := %ERROR_LEVEL%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### search & replace with GNU [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "qfile=file.sql"

set "tfile=%temp%\%random%.tmp"
(for /f %%i in ('sed -n "/DECLARE/, /BEGIN/ s/\(.*\)\s\w.*/\1/ p" "%qfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:~0,20!"
    echo(%%i !line!
    endlocal
))>"%tfile%"
for /f "usebackqtokens=1,2" %%i in ("%tfile%") do sed -i "/BEGIN/, $ s/%%i :=.*/%%i := %%%%j%%;/" "%qfile%"
del "%tfile%"
type "%qfile%"
```

.. output is:

```
DECLARE
  P_IBSP_YEAR VARCHAR2(32767);
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR VARCHAR2(32767);
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH VARCHAR2(32767);
  ERROR_LEVEL VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN
  P_IBSP_YEAR := %P_IBSP_YEAR%;
  P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR := %P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR%;
  P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH := %P_CD_PROCESSING_MONT%;
  ERROR_LEVEL := %ERROR_LEVEL%;

  T2_GDA.GDA.MAIN_RUN_ALL ( P_IBSP_YEAR, P_CD_PROCESSING_YEAR, P_CD_PROCESSING_MONTH, ERROR_LEVEL );
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Hello @Endoro.

Thank you for the reply.

I am unable to attach an image to show you, but I copied your code exactly as is in a batch file (bbb.bat)

And I replaced:

"qfile=file.sql" by "qfile=actual_location_of_sql_file"
"tfile=%temp%\%random%.tmp" by "tfile=actual_location_of_sql_file.tmp"

But when I execute my batch, the result was the same as the input.

I can't figure out how to attach an image to my comment to show u what I mean

Though the output YOU show is exactly what i want

Comment: I just noticed by putting an "echo on"  
When I look at the execution, it seems all your double percentages %% become single. For example this line:  

C:\>for /F "usebackqtokens=1,2" %i in ("c:\original_file.sql.tmp") do sed -i "/BEGIN/, $ s/%i :=.*/%i := %%j%;/" "c:\original_file.sql"

Comment: It's important to make a precise copy from forum, every space counts. Single `%`  in the `echo on` output is usual. Please post more input for testing, eg. on Pastebin.

Comment: I added all three info on Pastebin like you said.
If you have an email or something, I also took a printscreen where I show the code, the command line, and the original file all in one image.  
http://pastebin.com/LGEUDvir

Comment: [my output](http://pastebin.com/v8kZGzDk), look at the temp file `tfile=c:\original_file.sql.tmp`.

Comment: You are a genius !

Thank you sooo much.

The problem was that I have Unix Utilities defined in my "PATH" environment variable, so it wasn't working until I removed that. And now it works.
Again thank you so much

Comment: When using the code, it now works perfectly. However, I noticed that whenever I launch the code, I get a lot of files (32 of them) created in the c:\ directory, they all start with sed... (sed1e8Z3A, sed7B2CtN ...)  
Any ideas as to why ?


I identified it to be this command:  
for /f "usebackqtokens=1,2" %%i in ("%temp_file%") do sed -i "/BEGIN/, $ s/%%i :=.*/%%i := %%%%j%%;/" "%sql_file_location%"

Comment: It seems to be a bug from `sed`. I know now when it happens but not why. I can't change the code, it works. The files are temp-files from `sed`, where it stores the search pattern. For every replace it creates one temp-file. You can delete it with `del sed?????` , append the del command to the script.